# How to get SharePoint files properties by REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I could not find the right SharePoint API which will provide below information from a file.

[image: Files Attributes]

I am getting name and Title by using below API calls:

```
https://<tenant_id>/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<directory name>')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,ID, Title,Created,Modified,Editor/Title,File_x0020_Type&$expand=Editor&$top=50000
```

I want `Content Owner` and others fields along with name and title. Thanks!!

Comment: is it a Prerson field?

Comment: Yes, its contains a person name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work for you:

```
_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<directory name>')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,ID,%20Title,Created,Modified,Editor/Title,Content_x0020_Owner/Title,File_x0020_Type&$expand=Editor,Content_x0020_Owner&$top=50000`
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sandro!! It works

Comment: Hi @Sandro - Could you please tell me how do you know this is the exact name I have to put ina select statement in order to pull data. I need to pull some other columns as well. Thanks!!

Comment: @Dipak Use `_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<directory name>')/fields` to get all available fields. You can check a specific field using the following command `_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<directory name>')/fields$filter=Title eq '<fieldtitle>'`. This will return the property _TypeDisplayName_. If it is "Person or Group" use this [link](https://www.kofrimpong.com/sharepoint-person-or-group-field-properties/) to get all expandable properties. If it is "Lookup" you have to check the properties in the lookup list